# Using card views to display data

Tags: android, material-design

I am new to Material Design, and I have been reading about CardView.  I am changing my app's layout and trying to use more of the Material Design Guidelines in it. According to Google, "Cards provide context and an entry point to more robust information and views,"  this is the layout that I came up with. Sorry that it's in Russian.

[image]

On the top is a card with a search bar, and below that is a card with radio buttons that let you choose whether you want to sort your results alphabetically or numerically. Below that is gonna be a list of search results.

I really like this design, but I don't think this is the right implementation of CardViews, since it's not an entry point to more robust information, but I just used them to group thing.

Please let me know whether this layout/theme is good according to Material Design Guidelines.

Answer (score 0):

It is not good. I think merging the two cards into one make it better. According to Google: "Cards are a convenient means of displaying content composed of different elements". Just two small different elements do not make a better UI.

Comment: I appreciate you taking the time to answer. As I said, below that is gonna be a list. But yes, I could merge the 2 cards into 1. The thing that I was worried about is that those cards don't bring u to a page with more info about that specific topic.

Comment: Yes, I know. I mean merging the search bar & options into one cardview only. The idea of CardView is to merge different component of UIs which  relate to something (i.e they are related to search in your case)

Answer (score 0):

The good way of using `CardView` would be for search results, and you can merge `search` and `radio buttons` into single `CardView` without `margin` and corner `radius` then use CardView for each item in search result with `margin` and `corner radius`. That helps in segregating sections, one clearly for active elements(`Search and Radio Button`) and other for passive elements(`Search results`). So each search result can be clicked to show more details.

Comment: I appreciate you taking time to answer my question. I will merge the 2 cards together, but I don't know if I should use cards for search results. This is a song collection app, so the search results would be titles of songs. How would it look be if I merged the 2 card together, and had another CardView with  list/recycler view showing all the results